# QSerialPort with thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt5

I have been struggling a project that it communicates through the serial port in Qt for around two weeks. First I tried signal/slot method, it missed some data. Then I decided to use a thread for this, but I got the same result. While the application's window is being resized or maximized /minimized, even hold left mouse button on the window's bar, it missed some data. Please help me this condition.

The MainWindow Constructor:

```
SerialPort *serial= new SerialPort();
serial->moveToThread(&cThread);

connect(this , &MainWindow::finished, &cThread, &QThread::quit);
connect(this , &MainWindow::destroyed, this, &SerialPort::deleteLater);
connect(serial, &SerialPort::getData, this, &MainWindow::displayData);

cThread.start();
```

The Serial Port read thread:

```
void SerialPort::newData()
{
     mutex.lock();
     bArray.insert(bArray.length(),serial->readAll());
     mutex.unlock();

     emit getData(&bArray,&mutex);
}
```

The SerialPort Constructor:

```
serial = new QSerialPort();
connect(serial, &QSerialPort::readyRead, this,  &SerialPort::newData);

bArray.clear();

fill_serial_ports();
portName = find_stm32_port();

serial->setReadBufferSize(20*1024*1024); // it's a huge buffer.
bArray.reserve(20*1024*1024);  // it's a huge buffer.

open_serial_port();
```

Also, I thought that this can be a bug what misses some data and wrote to the bug tracker. Assignee said that QSerialPort never loses data furthermore, my code is wrong. I'm very confused, I don't know where to make mistakes. Please, could you check my other solution? Where is the mistake?

My bug tracker report (Not accepted) : https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-61233

Comment: Some example code please?

Comment: Off topic but... if your single threaded code was missing data from the port then I can't help feeling that moving that code to another thread is only going to make the *real* problem more difficult to debug.

Comment: If you are going to receive huge data from serial port it is possible that you have to accumulate data received from several readyRead signals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was solved by Denis Shienkov in qtbugreports. You can take a look the qsp-no-freeze-workaround-windows.zip example for serial port with thread.

Link : https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-61233

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your inner `QSerialPort` object `serial` to thread `cThread` too:

```
SerialPort *serial = new SerialPort();
serial->moveToThread(&cThread);
serial->serial.moveToThread(&cThread); // move you inner QSerialPort to cThread
```

In the code above inner field `serial->serial.moveToTheThread(...)` does the magic.

Comment: I will try this, also I thought that this can be a bug and wrote to the bug tracker.  Assignee said that QSerialPort never loses data furthermore, my code is wrong. I'm very confused, I don't know where to make mistakes. Please, could you check my other solution? Where is the mistake? I just added the link to my main post.

Comment: The problems with your code are the following:
1. Why `SerialPort` is inherited from `QThread`? You mixed 3 responsibilites inside your `SerialPort` class: (a) threading, (b) synchronization, (c) serial port wrapper. This can lead to unpredictable and really weird bugs.  Use aggregation instead of inheritance.
2. What's the reason to inherit `convertData` from `SerialPort`? This can be a real source of problems. Use `Chain of Responsibility` design pattern instead.
3. Add `serial->moveToThread(*this)` line to `SerialPort::SerialPort()`.
4. Refactor your code, try it again and come back.

Comment: I just now tried the terminal program in examples and added only a few lines code in order to start the MCU. It too missed data.If USB_Can converter's red led is on, it means that there is a missing transfer. However, while Hercules that is a serial port terminal program using, there is no missing data.
 You can see this in below video.
 Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7WvtYBLRY0YVFFmRzZvWWZKVFk/view

Answer (score 0):

> While the application's window is being resized or maximized /minimized, even hold left mouse button on the window's bar, it missed some data

I compiled [the code you provided to a bug tracker](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-61233), started it with a pair of virtual serial ports created with `socat`:

```
 socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0
```

and emulated sending data chunks, increasing their size by 1 byte each second:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..1000}
do
    dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/pts/25 bs=1 count=$i
    sleep 1
done
```

Your application's log looked like:

```
"bytearray length:1"
"bytearray length:2"
"bytearray length:3"
"bytearray length:4"
"bytearray length:5"
"bytearray length:6"
"bytearray length:7"
...
```

Then I tried to resize application window, move it, maximize/minimize, press buttons and so on. It has no effect: actually, no data has been lost at all (Ubuntu 16.04 x64) during a reasonably long test session. So if you still loose data, it's likely that the problem is in your virtual COM port with the description of "STMicroelectronics Virtual COM Port".

Comment: Thank you for your explain, but your test is quite slow than my application, My application's baud rate is 1Mbit (due to CANbus).

Comment: Alright, where do you think the data is lost? Does that occur in your convertData thread?

Comment: The USBCan device is giving an error about can't send data, so its error led is becoming on.

Answer (score 0):

As it's been clarified in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44374351/qserialport-with-thread/44380131?noredirect=1#comment75772989_44380131), the problem is that

> The USBCan device is giving an error about can't send data, so its error led is becoming on.

Try adding the following line right after creating `QSerialPort` instance `serial`:

```
serial->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::HardwareControl);
```

If your device supports RFC232 standard, this should enable RTS (Request to Send / CTS (Clear to Send) lines and cause your transmitter to request for the receiver's readiness before sending any data. See [here](http://www.brainboxes.com/faq/items/what-is-rts--cts-hardware-flow-control-) for details.